# Athena Partition Projection for Date column vs. String

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm looking to use Athena Partition Projection to analyze log files from AWS application load balancers and firehose emitted logs.  The data in S3 is prefixed with year/month/day and potentially hour as well.  I've been able to accomplish using the [Firehose Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-kinesis-firehose-example.html); however this example uses a string formatted partition column.

I'm looking to see if it's possible to use a date formatted partition column instead (with partition project and the firehose emitted s3 prefix format), as our query writers are already used to most of our queries involving date columns and it avoids the need to string format for relative date queries.  Is this possible or would the s3 prefixes need to be changed to accomplish?

**Table Properties for String column: *WORKS***

```
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `logdate` string)
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'projection.logdate.format'='yyyy/MM/dd', 
  'projection.logdate.interval'='1', 
  'projection.logdate.interval.unit'='DAYS', 
  'projection.logdate.range'='NOW-2YEARS,NOW', 
  'projection.logdate.type'='date',
  'storage.location.template'='s3://bucket/prefix/${logdate}')
```

**Table Properties for Date Partition column *Does Not Work***

```
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `logdate` date)
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'projection.logdate.format'='yyyy/MM/dd', 
  'projection.logdate.interval'='1', 
  'projection.logdate.interval.unit'='DAYS', 
  'projection.logdate.range'='NOW-2YEARS,NOW', 
  'projection.logdate.type'='date',
  'storage.location.template'='s3://bucket/prefix/${logdate}')
```

HIVE_INVALID_PARTITION_VALUE: Invalid partition value '2018/11/13' for DATE partition key: logdate=2018%2F11%2F13

Comment: The two `TBLPROPERTIES` listings are identical. Could you update the question with the properties that works? Also, post your partition keys and their types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the only thing you need to do is make sure the type of the `logdate` partition key to be `string`:

```
PARTITIONED BY (logdate string)
```

This is not the same as `projection.logdate.type`, which should continue to be `date`.

Partition keys with type `date` are just dates within the calculations partition projection performs. For all other purposes they are strings. PP will parse values using the date format you specify, do its calculations, then output strings using the same date format. This happens during query planning, before the Presto engine is involved.

Presto's schema-on-read approach means that you can say that a column has type `date` if its format matches the expected format of dates; `yyyy-MM-dd` in Java format. The format that you get from Firehose's S3 keys, `yyyy/MM/dd`, can't be cast to `date` automatically, it needs to be explicitly parsed:

```
parse_datetime(logdate, 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

I think it would have been great if PP would have been aware of the types of partition keys so that you could have done what you have tried to do, but I assume that since PP happens during query planning and most likely not anywhere near where the types of things are known it's probably too difficult to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the context and explanation regarding the partition key awareness. I figured it wasn't likely possible, but wanted to make sure. Maybe future versions will bring awareness.

Comment: pls look into my question as well. it's urgent. will be thankful to you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382264/invalid-table-property-for-input-string-0-23-property-projection-hour-digi